# how to use an curl to log in an server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, curl, afnetworking

I want to communicate with an server.

server need following information:

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "password": "secret",
    "password_confirmation": "secret",
    "seed_recipes": true          //not obligatory files
  }
}
```

here it is curl:

```
curl -d "user[email]=user@example.com" -d "user[password]=password" -d "user[password_confirmation]=password" -d "user[seed_recipes]=true" http://domain.com/users
```

I wrote following below, the server shows these errors

```
(
email =     (
        "can't be blank",
        "is invalid"
    );
    password =     (
        "can't be blank"
    );
```

and this is my code:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user[email]":email, @"user[password]":password, @"user[password_confirmation]":password_confirmation};

    [manager POST:@"http://domain.com/users" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

It seems that I may not sending the right message to the server. 
does any one knows how to right the curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user": @{@"email": email, @"password": password, @"password_confirmation": password_confirmation}};
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, can you provide me a reference? I am having trouble in turing different curls to jsons. I would like to study and learn them from bases.